# How to use tree-shaking for classes with Typescript and Webpack?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have a class named Car in the [file car.ts](https://github.com/blacksonic/typescript-webpack-tree-shaking/blob/master/app/car.ts) and two other classes for the engines in another [file engine.ts](https://github.com/blacksonic/typescript-webpack-tree-shaking/blob/master/app/engine.ts).

car.ts

```
import { V8Engine, Engine } from './engine';

class SportsCar {
  constructor(private engine: Engine) {}

  toString() {
    return this.engine.toString() + ' Sports Car';
  }
}
```

engine.ts

```
export interface Engine {
  toString(): string;
}

export class V6Engine implements Engine {
  toString() {
    return 'V6';
  }
}

export class V8Engine implements Engine {
  toString() {
    return 'V8';
  }
}

export function getVersion() {
  return '1.0';
}

console.log(new SportsCar(new V8Engine()).toString());
```

The car.ts file only imports the V8Engine class, but the V6Engine class also appears even in the minified file. The unused function i export from engine.ts is stripped.

When running Webpack without UglifyJS plugin, the V6Engine class is marked with `/* unused harmony export V6Engine */` as expected.
But after adding the plugin i get this warning message from UglifyJS:

```
WARNING in car.prod.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Dropping unused function getVersion [car.prod.bundle.js:89,9]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable V6Engine [car.prod.bundle.js:73,132]
```

I have [created a repository](https://github.com/blacksonic/typescript-webpack-tree-shaking) where the problem can be reproduced.
Cloning, installing and running `npm run webpack` and `npm run webpack-prod` reproduces the issue.

Don't know if this is a bug with the Typescript transpilation, UglifyJS or the orchestration of these tools.
I'm using Typescript 2.0-dev with es2015 modules and Webpack 2.1.0-beta.21.

Comment: I saw the issue you reported on the webpack repo, it looks like this is the right way to do it but is not tree-shaking because of an UglifyJs2 bug.

Comment: Solved it with Babili in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to output ES2015 modules and code and then run Babili minifier on it. It does the tree-shaking right.